# insert salaries in dept table group by dept, which is linked with employee table, in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

`Employee` table:

```
ID   EmpName   Salary   DeptID 
------------------------------
 1   'Anil'    10000      1  
 2   'Ram'     15000      2
```

`Dept` table:

```
ID    DeptName    Salary 
--------------------------
 1    'Accounts' 
 2    'Design'
```

The above two table are linked using primary key-foreign key relationship.

How to insert salary to all fields in Dept Table group by dept name in one query(T-SQL)?

Comment: Hello Mohan, Do you need dept wise salary details?

Comment: What if there a multiple employees with different salaries in a single department? What do you want to store in the `Dept` table? Average? Min? Max? Sum?

Comment: Bro you are working GGk @N.Dinesh.Reddy

Comment: It depends on requirement we will store Min,Max Or Sum but normally it is not required in most of the cases

Comment: Sum of salary group by dept has to be inserted to all the Salary fields of Dept table in one single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    Dept
SET
    Salary = salary_total
FROM    
    (SELECT DeptID, salary_total = SUM(Salary) FROM Employee GROUP BY DeptID) E 
WHERE
    E.DeptID= Dept.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to test this, but assuming that you want to sum the Salary for each Department and update the Dept table to reflect this should give you a starter;

```
WITH SalarySum as (
SELECT
    DeptID,
    SUM(Salary) AS SalarySum
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY
    DeptID
)
UPDATE d
SET Salary = s.SalarySum
FROM Dept d
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalarySum s
    on d.ID = s.DeptId
```